# How to permanently join MDB database (access) table with spatial data in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-joins

I have an Access file (*.mdb), and I want to join between this attribute data with its spatial data ? But other than (join & relate way) .

And I need it to be permanent .

Answer (score 3):

You can perform permanent joins using the **[Join Field](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000065000000)** tool which:

> Joins the contents of a table to another table based on a common
>   attribute field. The input table is updated to contain the fields from
>   the join table.

Answer (score 1):

You did not mention which part of ArcGIS you have your join.  In ArcMap, tabular joins are temporary by nature, To make a tabular join permanent you just need to export it to a new feature class.

If you are using the geoprocessing tools in the Toolbox (for Map or Catalog) or through python, you can use one of two methods.  The 'Join Field' tool (under Data Management Tools/Joins) will update the input table to include the joined data.  This alters the schema of your original data (there is no undo option).

The other method is to use the 'Add Join' tool (again under Data Management Tools/Joins) to create the join in memory like ArcMap's normal interface does and then use the 'Feature Class to Feature Class' tool (under Conversion Tools/To Geodatabase) to export to a new shapefile or geodatabase layer.

Answer (score 0):

After following the instructions in this link: https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s00000023000000
use "Build Raster Attribute Table" using the spatial data you wish to connect.  Then, you can now add the .mdb using Join Table if you right click the output in the Build Raster Attribute Table in the Table of Contents.